# Dynamic Select with error in where conditon

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

```
@P_SqLCommand NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT, --output which will be return
    @P_SqlList NVARCHAR(30),-- columns that needs to be filtered out
    @P_Table NVARCHAR(30),--Table Name needs to be use in the select statment
    @P_Input NVARCHAR(50),--the filter variable
    @P_Num varchar(5)
SET @P_Input='@P_Input'

    SET @P_SqLCommand='SELECT Top '+ @P_Num +' '+@P_SqlList+'  FROM '+
    @P_TABLE +' where '+ @P_SqlList + '=' + @P_Input;
```

give me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

Any suggestions ?

I am using SQL Server. What am trying to do is to use stored procedure to for dynamic select statement and pass through by parameters, it is work fine till the where statement.

How I can treat `@P_Input` as character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever value of `@P_SqlList` the final WHERE sentence will be something like:

```
WHERE [SOME_FIELD] = @P_Input
```

due you are setting it here:

```
SET @P_Input='@P_Input'
```

To solve this, add `@P_Input`to the parameters list. Or, build the whole filter outside the dynamic query and pass it as a single value:

```
WHERE ' + @Filter
```

This form allow you to build a more complicated WHERE sentence.